# Having Trouble webscraping Rakuten Finance data

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, web-scraping

Currently, I am trying to scrape financial data from Rakuten Finance(a Japanese website), which is shown in the red box here:

[image: screenshot].

I want to scrape the table highlighted by the red box (the source code is on the right). However, it seems like the website is getting data from somewhere else, and I am failing to get the most important part of data, which seems to be written in javascript. Also the source code that I get from ctrl and u and the source code from the inspector are very different. Why is that?

I have tried using Selenium to scrape the specific `div` tag, but it could not scrape anything.

Can someone help me?

Comment: what is the actual url for the website?

Comment: @Griffin You should add raw data, not screenshot or image link.